# Should I return a static UIImage or return a copy?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In a class named Utilities, I'm using a single static image to load up all the buttons in view, like this:

```
static UIImage *baseImage_bottomToolbarBG;

+ (void) initialize {
    baseImage_bottomToolbarBG = 
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-toolbar-background"];

    // take bottom-toolbar-background, which is huge, copy it down to size
    // at which it will actually be used
}

+ (void) dealloc {
    baseImage_bottomToolbarBG = nil;
}

+ (UIImage *)getBottomToolbarImagePortrait {
    return baseImage_bottomToolbarBG;
}
```

... and then to set up a button using this background image, I call this:

```
UIImage *image = [Utilities getBottomToolbarImage];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is this an OK practice, or in my `getBottomToolbarImage` should I make a copy of the static `UIImage` and return the copy?

This is using ARC and targeting iOS 4+

**Edit:** see new comment in `initialize` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to just ship a properly-scaled image as part of your application and always use `imageNamed:` to fetch it, because `imageNamed:` handles caching for you.

If you really don't want to do that for some reason, then your code is ok.  There's no reason to create additional copies of the image.

However, class objects never get destroyed, so you don't need the `dealloc` method.  In fact I would do it all in one method, like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)getBottomToolbarImagePortrait {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static UIImage *image;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-toolbar-background"];
        // Do [image retain] here if not using ARC
        // image scaling here
    });
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the better way to do this would be not to keep a static copy of the image around. Instead, create a static method like this:

```
+ (UIImage*)bottomToolbarImagePortrait {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-toolbar-background.png"];
}
```

The static class doesn't need to worry about memory management for the object; the calling class will need to take care of that itself.

A static UIImage could be changed in one place and unexpectedly affect another object trying to use the same image. The above method avoids this.

**EDIT**

In light of the fact that you're modifying the image and using that modified image in several places, I would implement your getter like this:

```
+ (UIImage*)bottomToolbarImagePortrait {
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[baseImage_bottomToolbarBG CGImage]];
}
```

Again, you don't want to keep using the same image as it may get modified unexpectedly in one place and affect another. The above makes a copy of the image and returns it.

Unfortunately, `[baseImage_bottomToolbarBG copy]` does not work as one would hope since UIImage does not conform to `NSCopy`.

Comment: This is probably the best way, since it means the image can get unloaded when it's not being used while under memory pressure (which UIImage, using this method, will take care of). If you still want to stick it in a static, then you need to `-retain` it, which will keep it around forever (although I believe UIImage can still unload the bitmap data if it's not being used while under memory pressure, but don't quote me on this).

Comment: I didn't specify in the original question, but I'm actually loading the original file, then shrinking it and keeping a static copy of the shrunken image. I don't want my app to be performing this operation every time I need a toolbar image.

Comment: @KevinBallard `UIImage` [is documented to purge the image data in a low-memory situation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW2).

Comment: @robmayoff: It says it "may" purge it. I would assume it will purge it as long as the image was loaded via a path from disk, but I cannot guarantee 100% that it will purge all images loaded via `+imageNamed:`, even though that's almost certainly the case.

Comment: That is true.  I thought the “iOS Performance in Depth“ video said it more strongly.  In fact it says specifically that `imageNamed:` releases the cached image on a memory warning, but doesn't specify the behavior of other images.

Comment: Is there a specific reason your original image is not saved in the right size? Why not shrink the image and save it to disk like that?